# Clean Html from contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to save contenteditable data to a javascript-array. Every new line should be an array-item

First of I cleaned out Chromes html:

```
html = html
//empty line looks like this:
.replace(/<div><br\s*[\/]?><\/div>/gi,'')
//Chrome wraps each line in a div
.replace(/<div>/gi,'\n')
.replace(/<\/div>/gi,'')
//Sometimes chrome adds a break.
.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi,'');
```

Later on I do:

```
html.split("\n");
```

I just tested in firefox, And realized that they make newlines by adding breaks. I haven't even looked at internet explorer yet.

Is there a more general-approach or well-tested way to extract just the text as lines of text separated by newline-carachter from html?

Comment: I really did not get the question

Comment: clarified the question

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="container" contenteditable=true></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.onblur = function () {
    console.log(this.innerText.split('\n'));
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/EZLhF/

Comment: This doesn't solve the question in the title at all.